Replace or repair black fiberboard in wall?
I demo'd the tub surround in the bathroom of my 1940s brick on frame house in Zone 6B where it gets both cold and hot. I found fiber board with holes in it - see pic. There is a 2 1/4" gap between the fiber board and the brick facade. Should I try to replace the fiber board? If so, how and with what? Otherwise how should I patch it?
I plan to insulate with rockwool. Is insulating with rockwool sufficient?

I would not touch the fiberboard sheathing.  That's more work than it's worth.  Rockwool, or XPS sheathing, cut to size, is what I would use.

gave you some points for good post, so you can do more here
